# Iterating through a sequence while modifying it. Use vector or List ? C++/ STL

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Suppose I have a long sequence of unordered elements S `s1, s2, s3,....` of a arbitrary but fixed data type through which I wish to iterate and delete certain elements according to some boolean criterion.

Now if after iterating through the sequence if I am ***not*** interested in the final ordering of the sequence then I can store my sequence in 2 ways

1. Use a plain ol' `std::list` to represent the sequence. Perform removal with the std::list methods.
2. Use a `std::vector` to represent the sequence. If a certain element fails the criterion and has to be deleted swap it with the last vector element and perform a `pop_back`.

My questions are

1.Which would be a better/efficient way timewise and/or memorywise to store my sequence?

2.If I had to venture a guess, then I would say list, because if `si` 's data-type memory size is large, swapping would be expensive. Would this reasoning be correct?

Comment: This is not possible to answer. You will have to measure the performance. If you would provide full source code, then we could maybe do some analysis, but in the current form, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: `std::vector` + `std::remove_if`.  I've never seen a situation yet where I wanted a `std::list` (I assume because I never needed a splice.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice, `std::vector` has a great performance advantage over other containers due to its tight memory locality. If your elements are moreover movable (i.e. inexpensive to swap), then your second option should be your first try. Implement it with the standard *remove/erase* idiom:

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), predicate), v.end());
```

You should also set up a second version with a `std::list` and compare the performance:

```
l.remove_if(predicate);
```

The list avoids moving any elements around, so in theory it could be efficient, however the practical effects of memory locality cannot be captured by the language standard and you cannot get around measuring and comparing the actual performance.

(Supposedly, if your element type is huge, like `sizeof(T) > 10000`, the list will probably start being faster than the vector. Test and compare, and keep your code modular such that changing this later is easy.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a C++11 compiler, or atleast an rvalue reference aware one, using swap will cost you nothing if your data type isn't flat (i.e., contains pointers to external resources or in other words, is expensive to copy) since it will just *move* your structs around. So if you have such a compiler, create a move constructor (read up on that) for the data type, and you're set. Just use a `std::vector` from there on.

Now if your structs are flat (no external resources), and are large, you might really want to use a `std::list`, since the memory overhead would be reasonably small in comparision to your data type's size. Since you only seem to be interested in bidirectional/sequential access to the elements, this might be just the right place to use a list.

A last point, and an important factor, *measure*. The default container to reach for should always be `std::vector`. Measure how both perform before blindly deciding on one. Another important factor is if you actually need to do anything else with the containers, like random-access or such stuff.

**Edit**: Before I forget, you might also just want to create a *view* over the container holding your data, which might be very cheap.

Answer (score 0):

We can only guess. I'd say that if the objects are easily copiable (e.g. basic types) then `std::vector` will be more efficient, as removing elements will not alloc/realloc/free any memory. But if the cost of copying elements is significant, then the `std::list` will be better.

But note that with C++11, the copy will be converted into a move, so you should consider the moving cost, that will be presumably quite less than the copy.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all practical cases, use `std::vector` initially. As always, write your code first then optimise later, if and when it is needed. If your profiler indicates that `vector`'s inefficiencies are the cause, then try a list. I've almost never seen a performance benefit from it though.